# elipsoid area function not giving correct results

Tags: php, math, pi

I have created a function to return the surface area of a given **ellipsoid dimension** but i am getting strange results.

Here is the function:

```
function elipsoid($a,$b,$c){
    
    $ab=$a*$b;
    $ab=pow($ab,1.6);
    
    $ac=$a*$c;
    $ac=pow($ac,1.6);
    
    $bc=$b*$c;
    $bc=pow($bc,1.6);
    
    $abacbc=$ab+$ac+$bc;
    $abacbc=$abacbc/3;
    
    $prepie=pow($abacbc,0.016);
    
    $fourpies=3.1415926535898*4;
    
    $elipsoidarea=$prepie*$fourpies;
    
    
    return $elipsoidarea;
    
}
```

If values of `$a`,`$b`,`$c` are all =`1` the result is `12.566370614359` which according to the ellipsoid calculator on google is correct.

If values of `$a`,`$b`,`$c` are all =`2` the result is `13.02034823541` which according to the ellipsoid calculator on google should be 50.26548.

I had my teenage daughter help translate this:

`S≈4π((ab)1.6+(ac)1.6+(bc)1.63)1/1.6` (copy pasted from google hence doesn't look like the equation now lol).

Into "idiot" form such that I can understand it.

Is the calculation translation correct and/or have I coded it right? I also question how according to google a 4m wide sphere can have a surface area of 50m? Is Google wrong as well as the many sites that have this calculation option?

Comment: 50m^2 sounds about right, and where did you get `0.016`? Shouldn't it be `0.625`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your doing wrong here,

```
$prepie = pow($abacbc,0.016);
```

It should be,

```
$prepie = pow($abacbc,0.625);
```

As of this,

[image: Formula]

root of `1.6` -> `1/1.6` -> `0.625`

Comment: thankyou for the solution i had translated 1/1.6 into the 0.016.